# Не работает удаление из структуры С

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Пишу добавление файлов в структуру и удаление их.
Вот данная функция. Она считывает данные из файла и заносит их в структуру. Потом вводится логин, и по этому логину удаляются данные из структуры. Но почему то когда вводишь логин, программа не удаляет а просто перестает работать. В чем проблема подскажите пожалуйста. Вот код добавления в структуру и удаление по логину из ее.

```
void userDELL()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char log1[100], pass1[100], log_f1[100], pass_f1[100], log_f2[100], pass_f2[100];
    text = fopen("user.txt", "r");

    printf("\n       Список зарегистрированных пользователей           \n");
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n   ЛОГИН              ||  ПАРОЛЬ\n\n");
    UserS *temper_user = new UserS;
    while (fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", &temper_user->login,&temper_user->pass) == 2)
    {
        printf("   %-18s || %s\n", &temper_user->login, &temper_user->pass);

    }

    printf("\nВведите логин пользователя которого вы хотите удалить: ");
    scanf_s("%s", log_f2);
    UserS * p = ab;
    if (p->login == log_f2)
    {
        if (p->next != NULL)
        {
            *p = *(p->next);
        }
        else
        {
            free(t);
            t = NULL;

        }
    }
    else
        while (p->next != NULL)
        {
            if (p->next->login == log_f2)
            {
                if (p->next->next != NULL)
                {
                    p->next = p->next->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    free(p->next);
                    p->next = NULL;

                };
                break;

            }
            p = p->next;
        };
}
```

Вот так вот выглядит сама структура UserS

```
struct UserS
{
    char login[50];
    char pass[50];
    char fio[50];
    struct UserS* next;
} *ab;
```

Comment: 1) Это не "структура", а список 2) И опять валите всё в одну кучу! Не нужно так делать. Напишите функции для работы со списком, отладьте их отдельно от основной программы. Вот когда заработают, тогда и используйте.

Comment: Так а почему по сути удаление то не происходит
У меня такое же стоит на удалении других записей из программы
Только там считывается с другого файла и добавляется

Comment: Ещё раз. 1) Вынесите функции работы со списком отдельно, тогда будет намного  легче разбираться с ними 2) Все ваши тестовые примеры прошагивайте в отладчике, смотрите своими глазами как ваш же код работает. Или вы думаете, что вас всю жизнь за ручку водить будут?

Comment: Вопрос помечен тэгом [C], но в коде присутствует `UserS *temper_user = new UserS;`. Это что еще за белиберда?

Comment: @AnT: Реально код, за исключением `new`, _очень_ сишный.

Comment: @OverLoader: Но вы всё же пользуйтесь либо парой `malloc`/`free`, либо `new`/`delete`. А то у вас `new`/`free`, это грубая ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (p->login == log_f2)
```

и

```
if (p->next->login == log_f2)
```

Здесь вы сравниваете два пойнтера (адреса) а не значения. Скорее всего то, что вы хотели бы сделать это

```
if (strcmp(p->login, log_f2) == 0)
```

Ещё обратите внимание на то, что длина `login = 50`, а `log_f2 = 100`. Перед использованием прочтите [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), возможно, вам будет удобнее использовать какой-то аналог к примеру [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/).